# How to change the value of array element in list of arrays? (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have list of arrays of labels and I want to change visibility of some label in some array in list by index. Tell me, please, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want:

```
    foreach (var l in list)
        if (l.Name.Equals("test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            l.Visible = false;
```

or:

```
    foreach (var l in list)
        if (l.TabIndex == 1)
            l.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: you are absolutely welcome. please don't forgot to mark it as answer to help others. thanks.

Comment: Of course, I just needed to wait a few minutes before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the specific label on your array location like you would access other variables in an array:

```
Label[] labels = new Label[10];
labels[0] = new Label();
labels[0].Text = "blablabla";
labels[0].Visible = true;
...
labels[9] = new Label();
labels[9].Text = "blablabla";
labels[9].Visible = false;
...
```

Of course the same goes for a List, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to change visibility of your labels with indexes. So something like that:

```
List<Label[]> labels;//your labels 

Label[] firstArray=labels[0];
Label[] secondArray=labels[1];
...

Label firstLabelInFirstArray=firstArray[0]; //get first label
Label secondLabelInFirstArray=firstArray[1]; //get second label

firstLabelInFirstArray.Visible=true; //In Windows Forms
firstLabelInFirstArray.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden; //In WPF
```